# Button Disable not working in IE 10

Tags: javascript

I have a save button, and initially when few fields are empty, it remains disable. this is working fine in all browsers but not in IE10.  I've tried many things to solve this, but nothing has worked. Any help is appreciated.

```
var numButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button').length;
for ( var num = 0; num < numButtons; num++) {

    var buttonName = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[num].innerHTML;

    if (buttonName == "Save" && id == dialogName) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('button')[num].disabled = true;

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: should `dialogName` be `"dialogName"`. Are you using the same ID` for more than one button?

Comment: For me [its working in IE 10](http://jsfiddle.net/3JNFw/) could there be a mistake in your `if(id == dialogName)`

Comment: Are you using any javascript library (jQuery, ExtJS, BackbornJS) in your code? I suggest to listen onSubmit event on the form and validate all the input fields. If validation fails then return false and show errors else return true and let the form to be submitted to server. By that way you may not need to write mention javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You have some undefined variables in your above code. I assumed them as following and this is running code for your problem.

```
window.onload = function () {
   var numButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button').length;
   for (var num = 0; num < numButtons; num++) {

      var buttonName = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[num].innerHTML;
      var id = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[num].getAttribute("id");;
      if (buttonName == "Save" && id == "dialogName") {
         document.getElementsByTagName('button')[num].disabled = true;

         break;
      }
   }
};
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppxyn/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the same issue, but I had a problem where I thought setting the disabled attribute wasn't working in IE 10. Turns out it was disabled when I clicked it, it just wasn't changing the style so it still looked enabled.